# Searching a json file for a item an displaying discord.js

Tags: json, discord.js

```
[
    {
        "name": “jack”,
        "age": “18”,
        "id": "1500"
    }

]
```

I want to make when i write this code “!name (name)”

The bot will then reply with

```
name: jack
age: 18
id: 1500
```

in a selected channel

Comment: can u post some code that you have tried till now? @Kaya

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

your json file:

```json
{
    "name": "jack",
    "age": "18",
    "id": "1500"
}
```

Import your json file:

```js
const json = require('./yourfile.json')
```

Send the message:

```js
message.reply({content: `name: ${json.name}\nage: ${json.age}\nid: ${json.id}`})
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not explaining exactly what I want. There is more than one information on the json file. I want to find the age and id of that user with "!name (name)".

Comment: use the `Object.keys`